# How do I debug a "[object ErrorEvent] thrown" error in my Karma/Jasmine tests?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I have several failing tests that only output `[object ErrorEvent] thrown`.  I don't see anything in the console that helps me pinpoint the offending code.  Is there something I need to do to track these down?

[EDIT]: I'm running Karma v1.70, Jasmine v2.7.0

Comment: Can you include more of the error? Like multiple lines of the error before and after?

Comment: `[object ErrorEvent] thrown` is literally all it says.  There is nothing before or after.

Comment: As luck would have it, I just got this issue literally the same time you were posting this question, it turned out to be a "rogue" script tag (it could also be css link) which needed to be removed (my issue was related to CORS), or in case of css, I just added crossorigin="anonymous". Check your code for such script/css tags, in my case I found the issue to be caused by a totally different component!

Comment: are you on angular cli aren't you? @DarrellBrogdon

Comment: @TheDude How did you narrow down this script? Line by line? Or was there some debug process that helped you narrow down where it was? I'm having the same issue and the only info I have to go on is the message: An error was thrown in afterAll. If I isolate the test itself by changing `it()` to `fit()`, even though only that single test is running, the error is still being thrown. Any debug recommendations for this type of error?

Comment: Have you tried importing HttpClientTestingModule to your unit test? That's what worked for my case.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

> FYI: you can find the exact error thrown just by open **DevTools Console** once your tests are running.

As a quickfix you can try to run your [tests without sourcemaps](https://angular.io/cli/test):

**CLI v6.0.8 and above**
 `--source-map=false`

**CLI v6.0.x early versions**
 `--sourceMap=false`

**CLI v1.x**
 `--sourcemaps=false`

> Shortcut `ng test -sm=false` might also work

There is an open issue on that https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7296

**UPDATE**:
I had that issue as well, so I just migrated to the latest cli and make sure that all packages are updated in `package.json` also I fully reinstalled the `node_modules` so now the issue has gone.

Comment: this worked for me. It helped reveal that the problem was with an undefined input binding.

Comment: As of Angular 6 `--sourcemaps` option is not present.

Comment: For angular-cli 6, `--sourceMap=false` seems to work.

Comment: typical front solution

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore. It used to, but in 6.2.4 it doesn't

Comment: I get Uncaught [object Object] thrown in random components and in some runs I get nothing... :S I hate Angular Testing.

Answer (score 53):

If sourcemap=false doesn't help, try to 
1) open your browser running the tests
2) click debug button
3) open the console

The error will be there

[image]

Comment: I didn't even need to click the debug button.  Just opening developer console worked for me.

Comment: Brilliant! I added the sourcemap option everywhere, but in the end this gave me the info I needed

Comment: The `--sourcemaps=false` thing wasn't working for me, but this worked flawlessly! Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't really help if the browser closes right after the test. Guess I'll write a bunch of useless tests to keep the window open, like some kind of caveman.

Answer (score 24):

Try if you get a more descriptive error message by running the test from the terminal, like this:

```
ng test -sm=false
```

In your test, you can replace

```
it('should...')
```

with

```
fit('should...')
```

Now only tests preceded by **fit** will run.
To leave the browser open after running the test, run the test like this:

```
ng test -sm=false --single-run false
```

---

Personally, I have encountered this error twice. Both were only triggered when calling fixture.detectChanges().

The **first** time, I solved it by using string interpolation more safely in my .html file.

**Unsafe** example:

```
<p>{{user.firstName}}</p>
```

**Safe(r)** example (note the question mark):

```
<p>{{user?.firstName}}</p>
```

The same may apply to property binding:

```
<p [innerText]="user?.firstName"></p>
```

---

The **second** time, I was using a DatePipe in my .html file, but the mock property that I used it on was not a date.

.html file:

```
<p>{{startDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</p>
```

.ts (mock-data) file (**wrong**):

```
let startDate = 'blablah';
```

.ts (mock-data) file (**correct**):

```
let startDate = '2018-01-26';
```

Comment: Any comment why '?' string interpretation is safer? This work in my scenario.

Comment: @DylanKapp this checks if the object is null before trying to read the object's property. See https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator for more details.

Answer (score 18):

This is because the jasmine framework can not handle the ErrorEvent type so it does not extract the error message and calls `error.toString()` on that object instead.

I just filed an issue at jasmine repo
https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1594

As long as it is not fixed, you can temporarily patch your installed jasmine package in the node_modules folder. In my case it is

`node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js`

and then change the implementation of the ExceptionFormatter from this

```
if (error.name && error.message) {
    message += error.name + ': ' + error.message;
} else {
    message += error.toString() + ' thrown';
}
```

to this

```
if (error.name && error.message) {
    message += error.name + ': ' + error.message;
} else if (error.message) {
    message += error.message;
} else {
    message += error.toString() + ' thrown';
}
```

It helps to identify the issue.

Comment: This worked for me in jasmine-core@2.99.1. However, I had to patch it in

 `node_modules/jasmine_core/lib/jasmine_core/jasmine.js`

Comment: So good - took a minute to find this post but it saved my butt.  Thanks.  Same jasmine-core version

Comment: After changing this, it only printed `uncaught` for me which wasn't helpful. So I added code to print `error` object and its properties.  `if(error){
       // message+=error;
        for(var propName in error) {
          propValue = error[propName]
          message+='error prop: '+propName+', value: '+propValue;
        }
      }
`. This provided extra info which helped me in debugging - eg`error prop: filename, value: blob:http://localhost:9881/11777e3a-28d8-414e-9047-cee7d328e843`

Answer (score 7):

For me it was related to having a promise resolved in the `ngOnInit` of a component. I had to use `async`, `fakeAsync` and tick as well as stubbing out the async service with `spyOn`

```
beforeEach(async(
  //... initialise testbed and component
))
beforeEach(fakeAsync(
  // ... setup mocks then call:
  component.ngOnInit()
  tick()
  fixture.detectChanges()
))
```

[Angular - How to unit test component with asynchronous service call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914105/angular-how-to-unit-test-component-with-asynchronous-service-call)

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: It may be related to testing routing.**

I'm getting `[object ErrorEvent] thrown` too.
An hour later, traced it to one line of code.

```
this.username = this.userService.getUser(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))[0];
```

The problem lies with the test environment attempting to evaluate `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')`.

If I replace it with `0`, `[object ErrorEvent] thrown` goes away.

My userService has a user like so:

```
public users = [ ["admin", "First name", "Surname", etc... ] ].
```

So `0` just gets this user, at index `0`.

Otherwise when normally running my app, `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')` is evaluated when the user selects a user to edit from my table of users.

So in my HTML, `*ngFor="let user of users; index as i"` loops to display all the users then `routerLink="/edit/{{i}}"` so you can click on edit buttons for each user, which when clicked go to e.g. `http://localhost:4200/edit/0` to edit the aforementioned admin user's details.

Answer (score 4):

what about cleaning after each test case:

```
  afterEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
  })
```

Comment: I read somewhere that the TestBed is reset anyway for each test.

Comment: I my case it helped clean-up for next tests.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this was caused by not defining an error handler for an api I was subscribed to.

My fix just involved adding the block of code to handle (err) below:

```
it('reports an error to subscribers of api calls if not authenticated', (done) => {
    let obsDataFound = dataService.find(1);
    obsDataFound.subscribe((app) => {
        // not expecting this block to be called
        done();
    }, (err) => {
        // This is the err block that I added that solved the problem
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        done();
    });

    let testRequest = httpMock.expectOne({method: 'GET'});
    const mockErrorResponse = { status: 401, statusText: 'Unauthorized test status message' };
    testRequest.flush(appTest, mockErrorResponse);
});
```

Comment: This was my case also, I was multicasting and one of the subscribers was not handling the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. One way this error happens is when you try to access anything null or undefined in template. Make sure you have safety checking on those variable.

For example this will throw [object: ErrorEvent] when config is undefined on component load.

**template.html**

```
<div *ngIf="config.options">
   .....
   ......
</div>
```

Do this instead

```
<div *ngIf="config?.options">
   .....
   ......
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What can help is, if you have the Chrome window open for your Karma test runner, to open the developer tools and check the console there. For me, this helped me to find out that the app could not use the Array.findIndex method on an undefined array (because the data structure was organized by a date string, such as data[2018][3][28],  and I happened to be pointing to the wrong date), but yet instead of just stopping at the error, the test kept running.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I would have expected the info to be present in the console, you saved a couple of hours of my life :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a race or an async test that isn't set up quite right or is used incorrectly. I would assume that the debug case needs to be fixed and ignore that the command line passes. Just keep refreshing the karma test runner (browser) in case the error `[object ErrorEvent] thrown` appears intermittently, then make sure you have implemented the async condition correctly.

Hopefully this works.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I had a test where I was accidentally using the **auth0-lock** library.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared to be an async problem, because after I added enough `it`s in one of my component specs, I was able to get a usable error message which pointed to a file and line within that file (it was related to `paramMap`.

In the spec that tested ParamMap, I just added:

```
  describe('this test', () => {
    it('will succeed', () => {
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('will succeed', () => {
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('will succeed', () => {
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('will succeed', () => {
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> [object ErrorEvent] thrown

This error shows that you have something undefined. The easiest way to debug it from my experience is :

```
it('should create', () => {
    console.log(component);
    // You can check in the browser log which property is undefined
    });
```

Comment: This has actually turned out to be the most useful reminder of all: in my tests I have a mock authentication service, that missed a method. Seemingly unrelated, one of the tests in a component failed, but not when isolated. I have tracked the obscure `[object ErrorEvent] thrown` down to that remote missing method only thanks to the console.log :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with the service, as one of the object wil be undefined during tests running.

Service code sample was something like below access to dom,

```
  const elem = this.document.querySelector(element) as HTMLElement;
  elem.scrollIntoView({param1: ''});
```

The specs referring to this service were failing with the error '**[object ErrorEvent] thrown**'.

I mocked my service object inside all the specs which were referring to this and the issue got resolved.

**Mock service**

```
class MockService {
serviceMethod(div) : void {
  testElement = document.querySelector('div') as HTMLElement;
  return testElement;
  } 
}
```

And use this mock service object in providers as below,

```
beforeEach(async(() => {

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [Component],
  providers: [
     { provide: Service, useClass: MockService },
    ],
})
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using a proxy in my application defined in proxy.conf.json like:

```
'/api': { 'target': 'some path', 'changeOrigin': false }
```

Because Karma wasn't aware of this proxy, it kept trowing errors in the console that the API endpoint could not be found.
So after looking in the Karma documentation, I found out that what I could do was to add the "proxies" property in karma.conf.js with the same object from the proxy.conf.json:

```
proxies: { '/api': { 'target': 'some path', 'changeOrigin': false }}
```

The error in the console was gone, and the [object errorEvent] was no longer thrown.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, what can worked for me:

```
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
  })
```