# Angular 4 testing - [object ErrorEvent] thrown

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, testbed

I'm in the process of completing the test bed for my angular application. But there is an issue in the karma-jasmine testing, which throws an error

> [object ErrorEvent] thrown

I updated the node_modules as a solution I found in the following link
[How do I debug a "[object ErrorEvent] thrown" error in my Karma/Jasmine tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722256/how-do-i-debug-a-object-errorevent-thrown-error-in-my-karma-jasmine-tests)

But now error throws at random times, sometimes test bed is completed without any fault, sometimes above error triggers. Any suggestions to avoid it permanently?

PS - Let me know in the comments if you need more resources. Thanks!

**SomeComponent.spec.ts**

```js
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { SomeComponent } from './some.component';
import { HttpLoaderFactory } from '../app.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from '../app-routing.module';    
import { SomeService } from './../services/some.service';

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  let component: SomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
        }),
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule ,
        RouterTestingModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        FormsModule, 
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        SomeComponent
       ],
      providers: [
        SomeService
       ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add your code thats throwing the error?

Comment: @JonathanCorrin added the code of the spec.ts. Error occurs at random times, most of the time if works.

Comment: any update on this? Same problem here, random tests, random moments.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it turned out that the upgrade to jasmine-core 3.0.0 cause the issue, so I downgraded to 2.5.2 and things worked fine.
I think that's because `karma-jasmine` is not yet compatible with `jasmine 3.0.0`

That's what I have now:

```
"jasmine": "2.5.2",
"jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
```

For more details about the issue see:

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1523

Comment: Had this issue with jasmine core v2.99.1 as well. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue too and afterAll() method resolved my problem. [my solution is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53608959/how-can-i-resolve-angular-unit-test-error-an-error-was-thrown-in-afterall-nob/53613647#53613647)

```
afterAll(() => {
 TestBed.resetTestingModule();
});
```