# How can I resolve Angular unit test error: "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown"

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

When I run `ng test` command in my angular project has error, it gives an error like that

```
10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active04 12 2018 11:29:43.408:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
04 12 2018 11:29:43.414:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
04 12 2018 11:29:43.414:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
04 12 2018 11:29:43.418:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
04 12 2018 11:29:53.540:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/    
04 12 2018 11:29:53.777:INFO [Chrome 70.0.3538 (Mac OS X 10.14.1)]: Connected on socket SKF3rI13kIK0WCqqAAAA with id 32081204
Chrome 70.0.3538 (Mac OS X 10.14.1): Executed 95 of 191 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.131 secs)
Chrome 70.0.3538 (Mac OS X 10.14.1) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown"
  }
Chrome 70.0.3538 (Mac OS X 10.14.1): Executed 96 of 191 ERROR (0 secs / 0.826 secs)
Chrome 70.0.3538 (Mac OS X 10.14.1) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent] thrown"
Chrome 70.0.3538 (Mac OS X 10.14.1): Executed 96 of 191 ERROR (1.386 secs / 0.826 secs)
```

That is the karma result, every test was passed.
[image: Karma test result, click]

My package.json content

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  },
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you have in your afterAll() method? (if anything)

Comment: I did not use `afterAll()` method.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the solution, in my case with

```
  afterAll(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
  });
```

method all errors disappear, there is sample code below

```
describe('Component', () => {

  let component: Component;

  beforeEach((() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [Component]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should have a defined component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
  });

});
```

Comment: As per your screenshot in question, there are a total of 195 tests to be executed. So, did u placed the afterAll method in each and every unit test file (xx.spec.ts) in your application?

Comment: Yes, I did change my all test files with afterAll() usage

Answer (score 8):

```
afterEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
});
```

This cleared the error for me.

Comment: yep, for me too