# Karma formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in

Tags: angular, jasmine, tdd, karma-jasmine

I understand the root of the error, the component I'm testing requires a `FormGroup` to be passed into it's `@Input() form: FormGroup`. I just can't figure out how to pass one in when testing this component.

There error occurs in my before each function when I call `fixture.detectChanges()` so the form must be passed in before that point

my current code get's the error group is not defined:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    Validators,
    FormBuilder
} from '@angular/forms';
import { StaticComponent } from '../../firewall/static/static.component';

describe('StaticComponent', () => {
    let component: StaticComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<StaticComponent>;

    beforeEach(
        async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [
                    StaticComponent
                ],
                imports: [
                    CommonModule,
                    ReactiveFormsModule,
                    FormsModule
                ],
                providers: [
                    NetworkService,
                    NetworkValidator,
                    HostNameValidator,
                    NotificationsService
                ]
            }).compileComponents();
        })
    );

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StaticComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ruleForm = FormBuilder.group({
            chain: ['chain', Validators.required],
            ip: [
                '',
                Validators.required,
                this.networkValidator.validateNetwork('ip')
            ],
            action: ['action', Validators.required]
        });
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    fit('should be created', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

**How do I pass in a pre-fab form to my @Input of the component during the test? I cant seem to provide FormBuilder correctly**

Comment: `form` is a public property on the component. Set it to an empty, or prebuilt, `FormGroup` in the unit test. Should work.

Comment: right, I tried doing component.form = FormGroup.group({...}) and I get error group is not a property. I import it but it's not injecting correctly

Comment: Can you ALL of the spec code to the question?

Comment: sorry i was cutting it down to be more straightforward, there it is

Comment: Exactly what I needed to see. Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a test component spec that I came up with for you. Notice the mocked `FormBuilder` that I have added and the way that I have provided it in the spec.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestingComponent } from './testing.component';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

describe('TestingComponent', () => {
  let component: TestingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestingComponent>;
  const formBuilder: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestingComponent ],
      providers: [ { provide: FormBuilder, useValue: formBuilder } ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestingComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.ruleForm = formBuilder.group({
      chain: ['chain', Validators.required],
            ip: [
                '',
                Validators.required
            ],
            action: ['action', Validators.required]
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This is my test component in case you need to refer to that.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testing',
  templateUrl: './testing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testing.component.css']
})
export class TestingComponent implements OnInit {
  ruleForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ruleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      chain: ['chain', Validators.required],
            ip: [
                '',
                Validators.required
            ],
            action: ['action', Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: hmmm. im getting syntax error ' Cannot find name 'formBuilder' ' in the useValue section

Comment: Did you add `const formBuilder: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();` toward the top of the spec, like I did?

Comment: That did it! thanks! I'm getting an error providing my custom validator service, but that is a separate question

Comment: maybe an upvote? I couldnt find help on providing the formBuilder anywhere else here or in the docs

Comment: still getting : [object ErrorEvent] thrown

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722256/how-do-i-debug-a-object-errorevent-thrown-error-in-my-karma-jasmine-tests

Comment: yeah I have sm set false, i'm following the github issue. I can't figure it out, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error after running `detectChanges`. My component's FormGroup, however, was initiated in ngOnInit, not passed as an input.

The solution for my case was wrapping the `component under test` in a wrapper component. This process will force Angular to put the `component under test` through the lifecycle events e.g. ngOnInit that you would otherwise have to invoke yourself. It also feels like the right way to test a component with inputs. It's a little more boilerplate, but this method mimics angular's natural behavior more closely.

Here is a reproduction of code from this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@AikoPath/testing-angular-components-with-input-3bd6c07cfaf6)

```
  describe('ComponentUnderTestComponent', () => {
    let testHostComponent: TestHostComponent;
    let testHostFixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ComponentUnderTestComponent, TestHostComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
    testHostFixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
    testHostComponent = testHostFixture.componentInstance;
    testHostFixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should show TEST INPUT', () => {
     expect(testHostFixture.nativeElement.querySelector('div').innerText)
         .toEqual('TEST INPUT');
  });

  @Component({
    selector: `host-component`,
    template: `<component-under-test input="test input"></component-under-test>`
  })
  class TestHostComponent {
  }
});
```