# How do I turn off source maps for Angular 6 ng test?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6, angular-test

I am trying to turn off sourcemaps for my tests in Angular 6. I know the sourcemaps switch has been removed, e.g., `ng test --sourcemaps=false`.

I have tried modifying my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "sourceMap": false
},
```

As referenced by the angular.json test -> configuration block:

```
"test": {
  ...
  "options": {
    ...
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
```

The source maps are still being generated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46840229/415078

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use

**CLI v6.0.8 and above** --source-map=false

**CLI v6.x**  --sourceMap=false

**CLI v1.x**  --sourcemaps=false

Comment: Thanks. Camel case and singular tense sensitive!

Comment: Please add 'CLI v6.0.8 and above --source-map=false' for people coming here and only reading the accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Angular CLI changing this param from version to version as per this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/46840229/415078):

**CLI v6.0.8 and above**
`--source-map=false`

**CLI v6.0.x early versions**
`--sourceMap=false`

**CLI v1.x**
`--sourcemaps=false`

> Shortcut `ng test -sm=false` might also work
>
> In case if you are on the latest CLI and none of above works you can
> always check the Options section at
> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/test.md
> for the recent param name

Comment: For the sake of change and breaking changes.

Answer (score 3):

Angular CLI v6.x reads --source-map as --sourceMap. So both --source-map and --sourceMap works for me for `CLI v6.0.8`

Go to package.json
Change `"test":"ng test"` to `"test":"ng test --source-map=false"` to turn off sourcemaps.

Please note it shoud be `--source-map` and not `--source-maps`.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I'm using Angular 10 and was able to set sourceMap for test in angular.json:

```
"test": {
  ...
  "options": {
    ...
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
    "sourceMap": false
```