# Angular 6 Karma Testing

Tags: unit-testing, angular6, karma-runner

This is a very weird issue after upgrading to Angular 6.

If I have 60 Test Cases exactly, Karma will fail
with the error msg "[object ErrorEvent] thrown"

If it is 59, 61 or any other no. of Test Cases, there will be no issue.

Also, if I have like 61 Test Cases and I skip 1 Test (XIT), it will also fail upon running 60 Active Test Cases.

Update: I have tried running active tests in multiple of 10s (e.g. 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 Test Cases and skipping the Rest). All failed.

Anyone having the same issue here?

Comment: Re-run your test again with the following command: `ng test --source-map=false` and it will show the real error.  Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50761206/how-do-i-turn-off-source-maps-for-angular-6-ng-test)

Comment: @dmcgrandle We tried

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running them in the browser, with `debug`?

Whenever I have this issue, it usually means there was an error in one of the test execution, and there is a console.log in the browser.

PS : i am using Angular 6

Comment: Yes I tried. But the error shown wasn't logical. If I add an additional "To Pass" Test Case in order to break the multiple of 10s, it will pass                                                                                                     
 `it('to pass', () => {

    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });`

Comment: What versions are you using? Mine is like
`"jasmine": "^2.99.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0"` & `"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",`